# How to input 1 byte integer value in C, C++

Tags: c, byte

I try to put a integer(-128->127) to 1 byte.
I use char
Here are my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

The result on the screen is right, but before program exit, it occurs corrupted. How to fix it for store integer in 1 byte, c, c++

Let's a example:
Input 128, 
my Console will printf -128: An error occur: "Stack around the variable 'x' was corrupted"
I work on Microsoft Visual Studio

Thanks, hope you help me!

Comment: A decimal value takes up more than 1 byte, so does it make sense that `scanf("%d", &x)` and `printf("%d", x)` will try to work with memory that you didn't allocate if you tell it that `x` is decimal?

Comment: `printf("%d", x);`` passing a character and promising an integer is wrong (same with scanf)

Comment: @DieterLücking, the `printf` is fine.  `x` will be correctly promoted to `int` by the default argument promotions.

Answer (score 5):

You want:

```
scanf("%hhd", &x);
```

From the [`scanf(3)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

> **`h`**
> Indicates that the conversion will be one of **`d`**, **`i`**, **`o`**, **`u`**, **`x`**, **`X`**, or **`n`** and the next pointer is a pointer to a **`short int`** or **`unsigned short int`** (rather than **`int`**).
>
> **`hh`**   As for **`h`**, but the next pointer is a pointer to a **`signed char`** or **`unsigned char`**.

.. and since it was mentioned below, from the C standard, **7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function**, paragraph 11:

> The length modifiers and their meanings are:
>
> **`hh`**
> Specifies that a following **`d`**, **`i`**, **`o`**, **`u`**, **`x`**, **`X`**, or **`n`** conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to **`signed char`** or **`unsigned char`**.

If you use a non-standard compiler, your mileage may vary (and you should probably retag your question).

Comment: Visual Studio don't support %hhd specifier?

Comment: @HiepMaiThanh This might be compiler dependent, the [documentation for Microsoft Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d.aspx) doesn't show it.

Comment: @MarkRansom, compiler dependent, maybe, but it's 100% standard - C11 7.21.6.2, paragraph 11.

Comment: @CarlNorum Visual Studio stopped being compliant with the latest C standards a long time ago. Their emphasis is on C++.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to do it is to read into an `int` variable, then copy to the `char`.

```
char x;
int i;
scanf("%d", &i);
x = (char) i;
```